# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on a site that doesn't use SSL/TLS, on an odd port

Tags: tls, chrome, hsts, jenkins

I've set up a server running Jenkins. The web-interface doesn't have SSL/TLS support turned on by default, and I have not attempted to turn it on, and do not want to turn it on (for now at least).

When I set this server up, (at say, `example.com:7070`), I accidentally typed in the url to visit it as `https://example.com:7070`, rather than `http://...`. The Jenkins server either didn't serve a TLS cert, or didn't know how to, but either way, I got a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. This is seemingly correct, as it didn't negotiate a TLS connection correctly.

What isn't correct, however, is that if I now try to go to `http://example.com:7070`, (the **non-HTTPS** url), I get auto-redirected by Chrome straight to `https://...`, and I can't convince it to go to the non-TLS version of the site. Of course, that means I just continue to get the `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` again, meaning I can't get to the site.

The site works absolutely fine (over `http://...`) in e.g. Firefox/Safari, so I can only conclude Chrome is somewhere storing information on TLS certs, and has incorrectly stated that it is expecting a TLS connection, and won't connect to the site without it.

Any suggestions or thoughts? How can I delete this information? (I've tried clearing browser history/cache to no avail.)

Comment: Check if the HTTPS request sent a HSTS header. That headers means "never contact me on HTTP, auto-switch to HTTPS". It's strange the browser accepted such header on a broken HTTPS connection... See http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers for clearing that HSTS data

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Please post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Xenos HSTS can only be sent with a response (not request) and ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR means there was no connection through which a response could return from the server to browser. Looks like a Chrome-specific quirk, which gets cleared together with HSTS data.

Comment: https://www.braindetour.com/2017/02/hsts-gitlab-and-letsencrypt/